# What is this green plant?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I have this green plant, and it flowered a few months ago, the flowers died, and I think it flowered purple or pink. It was at the front of my house earlier, planted by my house builder (MI Homes), and I moved it to my backyard. I live in North Carolina, United States. Here are my two pictures:

[image: Green unknown plant]

[image: Second Green unknown plant]

Comment: Looks like a yummy berry or currant. Could you ask the house builder who planted it?